# replaceAll type method that preserves special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

Currently, the `replaceAll` method of the `String` class, along with `Matcher.replaceAll` methods evaluate their arguments as regular expressions.

The problem I am having is that the replacement string I am passing to either of these methods contains a dollar sign (which of course has special meaning in a regular expression). An easy work-around to this would be to pass my replacement string to 'Matcher.quoteReplacement' as this produces a string with literal characters, and then pass this *sanitized* string to `replaceAll`.

Unfortunately, I can't do the above as I need to preserve the special characters as the resultant string is later used in operations where a reg ex is expected, and if I have escaped all the special characters this will break that contract.

Can someone please suggest a way I might achieve what I want to do? Many thanks.

EDIT: For clearer explanation, please find code example below:

```
String key = "USD";
String value = "$";

String content = "The figure is in USD";
String contentAfterReplacement;

contentAfterReplacement = content.replaceAll(key, value); //will throw an exception  as it will evaluate the $ in 'value' variable as special regex character

contentAfterReplacement = content.replaceAll(key, Matcher.quoteReplacement(value)); //Can't do this as contentAfterReplacement is passed on and later parsed as a regex (Ie, it can't have special characters escaped).
```

Comment: I am not certain what your issue is. Could you not just save the result of `matcher.quoteReplacement` to a temporary variable that you only use once for the regular expression? It would be more clear if you could provide a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method instead of `replaceAll`. `replaceAll` uses regex but `replace` doesn't use regex in replacement string.

Comment: Thank you anubhava - I'm embarrassed I missed something so obvious!